# Website getting reply from old ip

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2003, ip, website

I have changed a DNS entry (A record) in my AD server for a website address. But I was not able to browse the site after that. When I tried pinging and nslookup, I could find the web address getting reply from the old IP.

I have tried both flushdns and registerdns and its been more than 20 minutes now. I couldn't find any error or logs related to this in event logs too.

Please somebody help me. I would take this as high priority as this site is a clone of production environment.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible interpretations to your question here:

- You've updated a DNS record, but you're still seeing the old address, which means your connections are going to the wrong place.
- Your webserver is still listening on the old IP and not the new one.

If the former then you need to flush your cache, or wait for the record to expire.

If the latter you need to update.

As a compromise, assuming you still have access to both the old IP and the new you can configure the old address to forward traffic to the new destination - allowing users to visit the site regardless of which IP is used.

Comment: Thanks. That was fast.. But how long it would take the DNS to expire? I have already flushed the dns cache and registerdns. Pinging the dns entry answers me from the old ip and that is my issue.

Comment: Where are you testing from? What is the TTL set to on the record?

Comment: Its one hour :O , when I checked.. Anyway it is getting now.. Thanks All..